# Splitting a PDF with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript

I try to split a multipage PDF with Ghostscript, and I found the same solution on more sites and even on [ghostscript.com](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Use.htm#One_page_per_file), namely:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -o outname.%d.pdf input.pdf
```

But it seems not working for me, because it produces one file, with
all pages, and with the name *outname.1.pdf*.

When I add the start and end pages, then it is working fine, but I
want it to work without knowing those parameters.

In the gs-devel archive, I found a solution for this:
http://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2009-April/008310.html --
but I feel like doing it without `pdf_info`.

When I use a different device, for example `pswrite`, but same
parameters, it works correctly, producing as many ps files, as my
*input.pdf* contains.

Is this normal when using `pdfwrite`? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you see is "normal" behaviour: the current version of Ghostscript's `pdfwrite` output device does not support this feature. This is also (admittedly, somehow vaguely) documented in [Use.htm](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=blob_plain;f=gs/doc/Use.htm;hb=HEAD#One_page_per_file):

> ***"Note, however that the one page per file feature may not be supported by all devices...."***

I seem to remember that one of the Ghostscript developers mentioned on IRC that they *may* add this feature to pdfwrite in some future release, but it seems to necessitate some major code rewrite, which is why they haven't done it yet...

---

**Update:** As Gordon's comment already hinted at, as of [version 9.06](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=blob_plain;f=gs/doc/History9.htm) (released on July 31st, 2012), Ghostscript now supports the commandline as quoted in the question also for `pdfwrite`. (Gordon must have discovered the unofficial support for this already in 9.05, or he compiled his own executable from the pre-release sources which were not yet tagged as 9.06).

Comment: Yeah, I read this line, but my phrase "normal behaviour" wants to mean that "is pdfwrite one of those who may not support this feature?" Your remembering of this IRC is okay for me, Thank you.

Comment: For people finding this answer in searches: As of 9.05, one-page-per-file works for me with the OP's command.

Comment: @Gordon: Support for the `-o out_%d.pdf` syntax (to split multipage PDF into individual files per page) became official in 9.06. I hinted at this already in other answers (f.e. *[Split multi page PDF file into single pages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12744923/359307)*). I forgot to update this answer. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 43):

I found this script wriiten by Mr Weimer super useful:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# pdfsplit [input.pdf] [first_page] [last_page] [output.pdf] 
#
# Example: pdfsplit big_file.pdf 10 20 pages_ten_to_twenty.pdf
#
# written by: Westley Weimer, Wed Mar 19 17:58:09 EDT 2008
#
# The trick: ghostscript (gs) will do PDF splitting for you, it's just not
# obvious and the required defines are not listed in the manual page. 

if [ $# -lt 4 ] 
then
        echo "Usage: pdfsplit input.pdf first_page last_page output.pdf"
        exit 1
fi
gs -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$4" -dFirstPage=$2 -dLastPage=$3 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "$1"
```

Origin from : [http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~weimer/pdfsplit/pdfsplit](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Eweimer/pdfsplit/pdfsplit)

save it as `pdfsplit.sh`, see the magic happens.

[PDFSAM](http://www.pdfsam.org/) also could do the job. Available on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Amazing. I don't have pdftk and psselect would lose some pdf quality, but not this.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the -dFirstPage=… and -dLastPage=… parameters!

Answer (score 4):

```
 #!/bin/bash
#where $1 is the input filename

ournum=`gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "("$1") (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit" 2>/dev/null`
echo "Processing $ournum pages"
counter=1
while [ $counter -le $ournum ] ; do
    newname=`echo $1 | sed -e s/\.pdf//g`
    reallynewname=$newname-$counter.pdf
    counterplus=$((counter+1))
    # make the individual pdf page
    yes | gs -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$reallynewname" -dFirstPage=$counter -dLastPage=$counter -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "$1" >& /dev/null
    counter=$counterplus
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script for Windows command prompt (working also with drag and drop) assuming you have Ghostscript installed:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Customize or remove this line if you already have Ghostscript folders in your system PATH
set path=C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.22\lib;C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.22\bin;%path%

:start

echo Splitting "%~n1%~x1" into standalone single pages...
cd %~d1%~p1
rem getting number of pages of PDF with GhostScript
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`gswin64c -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(%~n1%~x1) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"`) do set "numpages=%%a"

for /L %%n in (1,1,%numpages%) do (
echo Extracting page %%n of %numpages%...
set "x=00%%n"
set "x=!x:~-3!"
gswin64c.exe -dNumRenderingThreads=2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dFirstPage=%%n -dLastPage=%%n -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="%~d1%~p1%~n1-!x!.pdf" %1
)

shift
if NOT x%1==x goto start

pause
```

Name this script something like `split PDF.bat` and put it on your desktop. Drag and drop one (or even more) multipage PDF on it and it will create one standalone PDF file for each page of your PDF, appending the suffix `-001`, `-002` and so on to the name to distinguish the pages.

You might need to customize (with relevant Ghostscript version) or remove the `set path=...` line if you already have Ghostscript folders in your system PATH environment variable.

It works for me under **Windows 10 with Ghostscript 9.22**. See comments to see if it can work with newer Ghostscript versions.

Comment: +1 for getting the page count with GS, good job! If anyone wants to get the page count on linux/macOS, use `gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(../escaped\ file \name.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"`

Comment: Very helpful. Does work with GS 9.22 but is somehow incompatible to (at least) 9.50 and 9.52. Somebody knows how to fix this?

Comment: @user18258 I don't know how to fix this but anyway I found more convenient to use another command line tool to split PDF files on Windows, `sedja` console. Here is a drag-and-drop batch: https://www.codepile.net/pile/6lWv3wzY

Comment: @mmj Thanks for the code based on `sedja`! I'm using GhostScript for a lot of 'shell:sendto' tasks and would still be interested in a 9.52 compatible solution - although I understand that you won't provide it. I found a small bug in your GS-based code above (which I'm still using with GS version 9.27!): I think that `gswin64c.exe ... "%1"` should be `gswin64c.exe ... %1`, or else there will be trouble when the path contains spaces.

Comment: @tstone-1 It seems that for Ghostscript 9.50+ you have to add the `-dNOSAFER` option (together with `-dNODISPLAY`). See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40156190

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple python script which does it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os

number_of_pages = 68
input_pdf = "abstracts_rev09.pdf"

for i in range(1, number_of_pages +1):
    os.system("gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=page{page:04d}.pdf"
              " -dFirstPage={page} -dLastPage={page}"
              " -sDEVICE=pdfwrite {input_pdf}"
              .format(page=i, input_pdf=input_pdf))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer which relies on `pdftk.exe` only, without invoking Ghostscript**

The answer provided by user @mmj used to work fine for me, but somehow ceased working somewhere between GS versions 9.20 and 9.50. I'm also aware of the solution provided by @Adobe. However, I like to get recurring tasks done from Windows (10) Explorer by selecting one or more files and going for right click → Send To. Here's a Python script (compatible to 3.8) that uses `pdftk.exe` (tested with 2.02) to count the total number of pages and extract all to single files. It should accept multiple PDFs as input. Make sure you have Python and `pdftk.exe` within PATH.

Name this `extract-pdf-pages-py.cmd` and put it to `shell:sendto`:

```
python %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\extract-pdf-pages-py.py %*
```

Put the following to `extract-pdf-pages-py.py` in the same folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# put as extract-pdf-pages-py.py to shell:sendto

import os
import subprocess
import re
import sys
import mimetypes


def is_tool(name):
    from shutil import which
    return which(name) is not None


if not is_tool('pdftk'):
    input('pdftk.exe not within PATH. Aborting...')
    raise SystemExit("pdftk.exe not within PATH.")

sys.argv.pop(0)

for j in range(len(sys.argv)):
    input_pdf = sys.argv[j]

    if 'application/pdf' not in mimetypes.guess_type(input_pdf):
        input(f"File {input_pdf} is not a PDF. Skipping...")
        continue

    savefile = input_pdf.rstrip('.pdf')

    numpages = subprocess.Popen(f"pdftk \"{input_pdf}\" dump_data", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output1 = str(numpages.communicate()[0])
    output2 = re.search("NumberOfPages: ([0-9]*)", output1)
    number_of_pages = int(output2.group(1))

    for i in range(1, number_of_pages + 1):
        os.system(f"pdftk \"{input_pdf}\" cat {i} output \"{savefile}\"{i:04d}.pdf")
```

I've used code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32259825/12246432) (script by @Adobe) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34177358/12246432) (`is_tool`).

Answer (score 0):

gs accepts only ascending order pages.
For shuffling (i.e. 7th, 8th, 5th) pages from the source I made function for ~/.bashrc:

```
function expdf
{
local str=""
local arr=($(echo $1 | tr "," "\n"))
#          splitting
for i in "${arr[@]}";do
  gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPageList=$i -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=$i.tmp $2
#          reordering for combining
  str="$str $i.tmp"
done
#          combining to combine.pdf
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=combine.pdf -dBATCH $str
#          removing temporary files
for i in "${arr[@]}";do rm $i.tmp;done
}
```

example of usage: `expdf 7-8,5 source.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Powershell version. (batch files are so 1990)

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438840/1964796

```
function expdf ($pdf, $pages, $out)
{
    $f = ((get-item $pdf).FullName.Replace('\', '/'))
    $o = "$out".Replace('\', '/')
    $count = gswin64c.exe -q -dNODISPLAY "--permit-file-read=$f" -c "($f) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
    (1..$count) | foreach-object { gswin64c.exe -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "-sPageList=$_" -dNOPAUSE "-sOutputFile=tmp-$_.pdf" $f }
    $pages = $pages | foreach-object { $_ } #flatten
    $pdfs = get-childitem "tmp-*.pdf" | where-object { $_.BaseName.Replace('tmp-','') -in $pages } | select-object -expand name
    gswin64c.exe -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE "-sOutputFile=$o" $pdfs
    remove-item "tmp-*.pdf"
}

expdf -pdf './test.pdf' -pages (1..3),6 -out out.pdf
```