# Find and replace content inside XML tags

Tags: xml, batch-file, vbscript, xml-parsing

I have configuration files in the form of XML. I wish to write to write a script to change certain properties in the files, for example

```
<database-param>
    <url>http://foo.doo</url>
</database-param>
```

I need to find the `<url>` inside `<database-param>` and further, then find and save+replace the string between `<url>` and `</url>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing tag data in an XML file using windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054275/changing-tag-data-in-an-xml-file-using-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft's XML Parser to read, write, and edit XML files in VBScript.  You can read my articles below to learn more.

[Creating an XML Document in WSH](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/windows-scripting/creating-an-xml-document-in-wsh/)

[Reading XML Files in WSH](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/windows-scripting/reading-xml-files-in-wsh/)

[Modifying XML Files in WSH](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/windows-scripting/modifying-xml-files-in-wsh/)