# Is it possible to change the WiFi hosted network settings using CMD/BAT/VBS?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, wifi

I was trying to change two **hosted network settings** of my **WiFi hotspot** using CMD/BAT/VBS, but I was unable to do it.

**The Settings I want to change:**

1. Authentication (eg: WPA,WPA2PSK)
2. Cipher (eg: CCMP/AES)

**The following code gives the information about the hosted network settings:**

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

**The following code sets the profile parameters:**

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter
```

**The problem is:** what is the profile name which runs the WiFi Hotspot.
The **profileparameter** asks for the profile name, and I dont know it.
I have tried exporting the profile but it does not contain the profile name.
Exported profile data is located in **windows/system32** directory.

**Is there a way to solve this issue?**

**Resource:**
[Netsh Commands for WLAN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890(v=ws.10).aspx#bkmk_wlanShowSettings)

Comment: Take a look at this ==> [Change the password for a Wi-Fi profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935746/change-the-password-for-a-wi-fi-profile?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks! I think this can be done by using: netsh wlan set profileparameter. But I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to get the profil name and its password with admin rights :

```
@echo off
Title Get the Wifi Profile Name with its password by Hackoo tested on french machine
cls & color 0A & echo.
Mode con cols=80 lines=5
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Set TmpLogFile=TmpLogkey.txt
Set LogFile=Wifikey_Log.txt
If Exist %TmpLogFile% Del %TmpLogFile%
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >%TmpLogFile% 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                 **************************************
ECHO                  Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                 **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show int ^|find /i "profil"') do ( set ProfilName=%%a
    Call:Trim "!ProfilName!"
    echo The profile name is : "!ProfilName!"
    echo The profile name is : "!ProfilName!" > %LogFile%
)
pause
Cls 
echo(
echo The password of your Wifi Network is :
Netsh wlan show profiles name="!ProfilName!" key=clear |Find /i "Conten"
(
    echo The password of your Wifi Network is :
    Netsh wlan show profiles name="!ProfilName!" key=clear |Find /i "Conten"
)>>%LogFile%
pause
Start "" %LogFile%
 ::*************************************************************************************
:Trim <String>
(
    echo Wscript.echo Trim("%~1"^)
)>"%~n0.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%~n0.vbs"') do ( set "Profilname=%%a" )
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
```

---

EDIT : 10/10/2020 New Version in HTA : [Wifi Passwords Recovery.hta](https://pastebin.com/DnvhmT72)

[image]

Comment: Tried the code but not getting the profile name. Its showing the interfaces - Name, Hardware Info, Mac address, GUID, State.

Comment: @SoftwareBuilder I edit my answer please check it and give me your result !

Comment: It is not working! Are you getting the profile name in your computer?

Comment: @SoftwareBuilder  Yes ! and i'm working on french machine

Comment: I have saved it as a BAT file and also run as ADMINISTRATOR but still it is not working. Do you have an alternate solution?

Comment: @SoftwareBuilder Please check again on your machine, i edited my answer to execute the script with admin rights !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109576/discussion-between-hackoo-and-software-builder).