# How to extract lines and its coordinates from a PDF file using Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a pdf file which contains some lines (not text) with different line width. I need to extract the co-ordinates of the starting and ending of those lines. Is it possible to do this using python. Any help will be really helpful.

Please note I don't need to extract text. I need to extract the lines.

Comment: Have you tried inkscape or something similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288065/convert-pdf-to-clean-svg I guess you would want to extract the lines from a SVG file

Comment: @Timothy Dalton I need to extract lines from pdf and not from svg. Also I'm not familiar with inkscape. If you give some overview, it will be helpful.

Comment: I would try and convert the pdf to an svg with Inkscape and see if you can select the lines   then.

Comment: It is theoretically possible. You would have to parse the compressed PostScript that the `.pdf` format uses and pick out the commands that draw the lines. Writing such a parser would be a significant project.