# Check if a program exists from a python script

Tags: python

How do I check if a program exists from a python script?

Let's say you want to check if `wget` or `curl` are available. We'll assume that they should be in path.

It would be the best to see a multiplatform solution but for the moment, Linux is enough.

Hints:

- running the command and checking for return code is not always enough as some tools do return non 0 result even when you try `--version`.
- nothing should be visible on screen when checking for the command

Also, I would appreciate a solution that that is more general, like `is_tool(name)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import subprocess
import os

def is_tool(name):
    try:
        devnull = open(os.devnull)
        subprocess.Popen([name], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull).communicate()
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This would leave the subprocess running indefinitely if it fills the pipe buffers of either stdout or stderr.  If you want to run the process *at all* just to check if it exists, you should use open `os.devnull` and use it as stdout and stderr.

Comment: not likely to happen but you are right, thanks.

Comment: Many tools output usage information when called without parameters, which could easily fill the pipe buffers.  I was wrong with my initial comment anyway – I missed the call to `comunnicate()`, which was beyond the right margin of the code box, and I did not scroll far enough to the right.  The method `Popen.communicate()` takes care of avoiding any deadlocks.

Comment: Make sure to open /dev/null for *writing* ie: ``open(os.devnull, "w")``

Comment: Also just a FYI for people using Python 3.3 and later, you can use `subprocess.DEVNULL` rather than `open(os.devnull)`.

Comment: You will also need to close `os.devnull` after opening. Otherwise if executing many times, there will be too many handles open and ultimately it will exceed the limit.

Answer (score 218):

## shutil.which

Let me recommend an option that has not been discussed yet: a Python implementation of `which`, specifically [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which). It was introduced in Python 3.3 and is cross-platform, supporting Linux, Mac, and Windows. It is also available in Python 2.x via [whichcraft](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whichcraft). You can also just rip the code for `which` right out of whichcraft [here](https://github.com/pydanny/whichcraft/blob/master/whichcraft.py#L20) and insert it into your program.

```
def is_tool(name):
    """Check whether `name` is on PATH and marked as executable."""

    # from whichcraft import which
    from shutil import which

    return which(name) is not None
```

---

## distutils.spawn.find_executable

Another option that has already been mentioned is `distutils.spawn.find_executable`.

`find_executable`'s docstring is as follows:

> Tries to find 'executable' in the directories listed in 'path'

So if you pay attention, you'll note that the name of the function is somewhat misleading. Unlike `which`, `find_executable` does not actually verify that `executable` is marked as executable, only that it is on the PATH. So it's entirely possible (however unlikely) that `find_executable` indicates a program is available when it is not.

For example, suppose you have a file `/usr/bin/wget` that is not marked executable. Running `wget` from the shell will result in the following error: *bash: /usr/bin/wget: Permission denied*. `which('wget') is not None` will return False, yet `find_executable('wget') is not None` will return True. You can probably get away with using either function, but this is just something to be aware of with `find_executable`.

```
def is_tool(name):
    """Check whether `name` is on PATH."""

    from distutils.spawn import find_executable

    return find_executable(name) is not None
```

Comment: Link to docs for `shutil.which()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which

Comment: up vote for distutils.spawn.find_executable! Thanks man!

Comment: If the Python function follows the shell command... `which` is not a good choice. You should probably use `command -v` instead. Also see [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) and [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639)

Comment: Check the source to `shutil.which` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3e986de0d65e78901b55d4e500b1d05c847b6d5e/Lib/shutil.py#L1291 or https://github.com/pydanny/whichcraft/blob/master/whichcraft.py#L20. It's pure Python and doesn't call the `which` binary so none of the arguments made in those answers are relevant.

Comment: Could someone help me understand the `return which(name) is not None` line?

Comment: @PeterSchorn find_executable(name) returns None if it doesnt find anything. so in None is not None will be `False`, hence `return False`. when it is not `None`, therefore the condition becomes `True` and returns `True`.

Answer (score 56):

The easiest way is to try to run the program with the desired parameters, and handle the exception if it doesn't exist:

```
try:
    subprocess.call(["wget", "your", "parameters", "here"])
except FileNotFoundError:
    # handle file not found error.
```

This is a common pattern in Python: [EAFP](http://docs.python.org//glossary.html#term-eafp)

In Python 2, you had to catch `OsError` instead, since the more fine-grained exception classes for OS errors did not exist yet:

```
try:
    subprocess.call(["wget", "your", "parameters", "here"])
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        # handle file not found error.
    else:
        # Something else went wrong while trying to run `wget`
        raise
```

Comment: right. for programs you know how to use, this is probably the best way to go about it. After all: expecting success often leads to cleaner code...

Comment: @DarenThomas: For programs you don't know how to use, the information whether they exist or not doesn't seem to be too useful. :)

Comment: I like your approach, but it does pollute the stdout and stderr. Also, it is not a function ;)

Comment: @SorinSbarnea: How does this pollute stdout and stderr?  Since I cannot think of any other reason for testing whether `wget` exists, I'm assuming you are going to run it anyway.

Comment: Your solution will display output of the executed command, look at my solution, based on yours, which is totally quiet. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11210902/99834

Comment: @SorinSbarnea: My approach is a completely different one.  The only reason you might be testing if a command exists is that you are planning to run it.  My recommendation is:  Don't test in advance, just run it, and catch the exception if things fail.  This does not pollute stdout or stderr in any way, and it will lead to cleaner code and less overhead.

Comment: @SvenMarnach "The only reason you might be testing if a command exists is that you are planning to run it." A different example: if you are making an install script that will skip some steps if they are unnecessary, then you may want to simply check if the commands already exist, then if not, install. Not the best solution, but sometimes good enough. The install script doesn't run those, just makes sure that they are available.

Comment: @Ctrl-C Makes sense as a use case.  I recommend the answer by Six instead – `shutil.which` wasn't available at the time I wrote this answer.

Comment: `errno` is its own module so the test should be `if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:`

Comment: @Mike Yeah, probably. In Python 2, it was possible to access the `errno` module via `os`, but that was probably never meant to be exposed – I'll update the answer.

Comment: At least in Python 3, an arguably cleaner way is to catch `FileNotFoundError` directly. saves the if

Comment: @fabian789 Good point, updated the answer.

Answer (score 15):

You could use a subprocess call to the binary needed with :

- "which" : *nix
- "where" : Win 2003 and later (Xp has an addon)

to get the executable path (supposing it is in the environment path).

```
import os 
import platform
import subprocess

cmd = "where" if platform.system() == "Windows" else "which"
try: 
    subprocess.call([cmd, your_executable_to_check_here])
except: 
    print "No executable"
```

or just use Ned Batchelder's wh.py script, that is a "which" cross platform implementation:

http://nedbatchelder.com/code/utilities/wh_py.html

Comment: call doesn't throw an exception when the program doesn't exist, instead the call returns non-zero

Answer (score 13):

I would probably shell out to `which wget` or `which curl` and check that the result ends in the name of the program you are using. The magic of unix :)

Actually, all you need to do is check the return code of `which`. So... using our trusty `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

rc = subprocess.call(['which', 'wget'])
if rc == 0:
    print('wget installed!')
else:
    print('wget missing in path!')
```

Note that I tested this on windows with cygwin... If you want to figure out how to implement `which` in pure python, i suggest you check here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycoreutils (oh dear - it seems they don't supply `which`. Time for a friendly nudge?)

**UPDATE**: On Windows, you can use `where` instead of `which` for a similar effect.

Comment: Wouldn't this try to run a program named `"which wget"`, i.e. with a space in the filename?

Comment: @SvenMarnach, right! I got the syntax all wrong :( oh dear.

Comment: This should be: `subprocess.call(['which', 'wget'])`

Comment: @nbubis, thank you! i updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Sadly, this solution does not work for Windows platform

Comment: `which` is not a good choice. You should probably use `command -v` instead. Also see [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) and [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639)

Answer (score 12):

I'd go for:

```
import distutils.spawn

def is_tool(name):
  return distutils.spawn.find_executable(name) is not None
```

Comment: `distutils.spawn` works well in Linux and Mac OS X. But in the latter one, if you make a `app`, and you double click to execute,  `distutils.spawn` always returns `None`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd change @sorin's answer as follows, the reason is it would check the name of the program without passing the absolute path of the program

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def check_program_exists(name):
    p = Popen(['/usr/bin/which', name], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    p.communicate()
    return p.returncode == 0
```

Comment: Sadly, this solution does not work for Windows platform

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot Thanks for telling me that, I don't have Windows platform to test.

Comment: `which` is not portable, not posix and not installed by default on most platforms. Look for `command -v` or `type`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import subprocess


def is_tool(prog):
    for dir in os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir, prog)):
            try:
                subprocess.call([os.path.join(dir, prog)],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            except OSError, e:
                return False
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: This is not platform-independent:  If you really want to replicate OS functionality, you should at least use `os.path.join()` and `os.pathsep`.

Comment: (I also edited in `os.pathsep` – on Windows, `PATH` is semicolon-delimited.)

Comment: good catch, did my edit overwrite your pathsep?

Comment: I like your function, but for programs that runs in interactive mode it does not work very well. Try for instance `nslookup`.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to @SvenMarnach's code that addresses the issue of printing to the standard output stream.  If you use the `subprocess.check_output()` function rather than `subprocess.call()` then you can handle the string that is normally printed to standard out in your code and still catch exceptions and the exit status code.

If you want to suppress the standard output stream in the terminal, don’t print the std out string that is returned from `check_output`:

```
import subprocess
import os
try:
    stdout_string = subprocess.check_output(["wget", "--help"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    # print(stdout_string)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    print(cpe.returncode)
    print(cpe.output)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
        print(e)
    else:
        # Something else went wrong while trying to run `wget`
        print(e)
```

The non-zero exit status code and output string are raised in the `CalledProcessError` as  `subprocess.CalledProcessError.returncode` and `subprocess.CalledProcessError.output` so you can do whatever you'd like with them.

If you want to print the executable's standard output to the terminal, print the string that is returned:

```
import subprocess
import os
try:
    stdout_string = subprocess.check_output(["wget", "--help"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(stdout_string)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    print(cpe.returncode)
    print(cpe.output)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
        print(e)
    else:
        # Something else went wrong while trying to run `wget`
        print(e)
```

`print()` adds an extra newline to the string.  If you want to eliminate that (and write std error to the std err stream instead of the std out stream as shown with the print() statements above), use `sys.stdout.write(string)` and `sys.stderr.write(string)` instead of print():

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
try:
    stdout_string = subprocess.check_output(["bogus"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    sys.stdout.write(stdout_string)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
    sys.stderr.write(cpe.returncode)
    sys.stderr.write(cpe.output)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
        sys.stderr.write(e.strerror)
    else:
        # Something else went wrong while trying to run `wget`
        sys.stderr.write(e.strerror)
```