# Windows subprocess.Popen a batch file without shell=True

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

I have a function that runs `lessc` (installed with `npm install -g less`):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['lessc'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work unless I add `shell=True`:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['lessc'], shell=True)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x01F619D0>
```

What can I do to make `lessc` run without using `shell=True`?

Comment: Can you call the binary explicitly with its full path name without using `shell=True`?

Comment: @kragniz: `lessc` is a batch file (which might actually be the problem) and the same error occurs when I run it with the full path.

Comment: Is the error generated by the subprocess module itself or by the batch script? You can add `cwd=r'c:\path\to\script\'` argument on Popen call

Comment: @JBernardo: The `subprocess` module. So there's no way to get around this problem without editing the script itself (it's part of an asset bundler for a web framework)?

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen): On Windows with `shell=True`, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify `shell=True` on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch file or console-based executable.

Comment: have you tried setting the `cwd` argument like I said above?

Comment: @JBernardo: I'm still trying to figure out how to integrate it into the existing code, but I'll get back to you in a few minutes when it works.

Comment: @JBernardo: Yep, that fixed `lessc`, but now `uglifyjs` is breaking (probably for some unrelated reason). Thanks!

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor *(...) this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to `cwd`.* It seems like it's not the fact you added `cwd` that fixed the problem but something else like running your python script from different directory.

Answer (score 1):

From both https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen and https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen:

> You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch file or console-based executable.

as already [cited by @JBernardo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137556/windows-subprocess-popen-a-batch-file-without-shell-true#comment23054228_16137556).

So, lets try:

`where lessc` actually tells

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd
```

That means, the file to execute is `lessc.cmd`, not some `.bat` file. And indeed:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x035BA070>
>>> lessc: no input files

usage: lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]
```

So, this *does* work if you specify the full path. I assume there was a typo involved when you had [this experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137556/windows-subprocess-popen-a-batch-file-without-shell-true#comment23054022_16137556). May be you wrote `.bat` instead of `.cmd`?

---

If you don't want to patch the full path of `lessc` into your script, you can bake yourself a `where`:

```
import plaform
import os

def where(file_name):
    # inspired by http://nedbatchelder.com/code/utilities/wh.py
    # see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210104/
    path_sep = ":" if platform.system() == "Linux" else ";"
    path_ext = [''] if platform.system() == "Linux" or '.' in file_name else os.environ["PATHEXT"].split(path_sep)
    for d in os.environ["PATH"].split(path_sep):
        for e in path_ext:
            file_path = os.path.join(d, file_name + e)
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                return file_path
    raise Exception(file_name + " not found")
```

Then you can write:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([where('lessc')])
```

Comment: `lessc` would have been at version 1.3.3 and `npm` at 1.2.18 when I asked this question five years ago. I don't have a Windows environment to test this with at the moment so perhaps something changed since then?

Answer (score 0):

Change the file to lessc.bat, or create .bat file that calls lessc. That way the file will be recognized by Windows as a batch file and will be executed properly.

You may also need to set cwd in addition to this depending on where the .bat file is.