# Check if a program is installed with Python

Tags: python-3.x, linux

My code requires that UFW (Uncomplicated firewall) is installed. The program will only be run on a Linux based OS. How would I go about having Python return a value if it finds UFW installed?

Edit: Instead of catching the output, I want to see if the folder (in the default installation path) exists.

Comment: How would you check if UFW is installed from the command line? Can you arrange to run the same commands using Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['which' equivalent function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226958/which-equivalent-function-in-python)

Comment: I'm aware I could just run the command and catch the output, but I want to see if the folder (in the default installation path) exists or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['which' equivalent function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5226958/608639), [Test if executable exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377017/608639), [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please note this is just an edited copy of links

1. [How do I check if directory exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python)
2. [Check if a program exists from a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210104/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-python-script/34177358)

Hope This helps

```
import subprocess
rc = subprocess.call(['which', 'ufw'])
if rc == 0:
    print('ufw installed!')
else:
    print('ufw missing in path!')

# To check whether path exists
import os

if os.path.exists("/usr/sbin/ufw") :
  print("path exists")
else:
  print("path doesn't exist")
```