# problem running "command -v dnf" in python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, command

I'm trying to run this code:

```py
import subprocess
def install_curl():
    result = subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'dnf']) # 
    if not result:
        print("You should Install curl")
    else:
        result = subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'apt'])
        print(result)
install_curl()
```

Then I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pbravodez1/projects/Automate_task/test_gpg.py", line 98, in <module>
    install_curl()
  File "/home/pbravodez1/projects/Automate_task/test_gpg.py", line 91, in install_curl
    result = subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'dnf']) # 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'command'
```

Do you have any idea on how to run this "command" in order to check which package manager is installed in the Operating System?

Comment: Please format (indent) your python code properly

Comment: Thanks @JanStránský but it seems that when I was writing this question turns like that. My code is well indented on my side.

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210104/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-python-script)

Comment: Seems like `command` is a BASH-specific, not available in Python (similar to BASH aliases defined in `.bashrc` file)

Comment: Thanks again @JanStránský and yes seems like. I was trying to make it in a nice and short way. I will take a look at the link you suggested.